# ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all() for list of arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x

CODE:

```
for i in group2:
  print(i)
  if i in mod_list2:
    print("True")
    mod_list2.remove(i)
```

OUTPUT:

```
['cash', array([[163.,  57.],
       [192.,  66.]], dtype=float32)]
True
['50', array([[175.,  67.],
       [196.,  80.]], dtype=float32)]
True
['s', array([[164.,  70.],
     [170.,  77.]], dtype=float32)]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-262-24bc7cfe9622> in <module>()
      1 for i in group2:
      2   print(i)
----> 3   if i in mod_list2:
      4     print("True")
      5     mod_list2.remove(i)

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I don't understand why I am getting this error. It is working fine for remaining elements without converting to list or any() or all(). For element 's', when I checked it manually. Like, Load the `['s', array([[164.,  70.], [170.,  77.]], dtype=float32)]` element based on the index position.

mod_list2:

```
[['15', array([[170.,  19.],
         [202.,  47.]], dtype=float32)], ['s', array([[163.,  32.],
         [173.,  45.]], dtype=float32)], ['kohls', array([[162.,  46.],
         [199.,  57.]], dtype=float32)], ['cash', array([[163.,  57.],
         [192.,  66.]], dtype=float32)], ['50', array([[175.,  67.],
         [196.,  80.]], dtype=float32)], ['s', array([[164.,  70.],
         [170.,  77.]], dtype=float32)], ['34948',
  array([[ 13.244825, 104.16207 ],
         [ 57.793106, 117.48275 ]], dtype=float32)], ['15',
  array([[163., 119.],
         [187., 137.]], dtype=float32)], ['of', array([[185., 130.],
         [195., 136.]], dtype=float32)], ['coan', array([[132., 139.],
         [150., 145.]], dtype=float32)]]
```

group2:

```
[['15', array([[170.,  19.],
         [202.,  47.]], dtype=float32)], ['kohls', array([[162.,  46.],
         [199.,  57.]], dtype=float32)], ['cash', array([[163.,  57.],
         [192.,  66.]], dtype=float32)], ['50', array([[175.,  67.],
         [196.,  80.]], dtype=float32)], ['s', array([[164.,  70.],
         [170.,  77.]], dtype=float32)]]
```

Thanks

Comment: "for list of lists" What you show are arrays of arrays, not lists of lists.

Comment: Did you *intend* these to be ``list``s and are confused that they are not, or to be ``array``s and are confused that the operation does not work? The error is telling you how to fix it, have you tried any of the variants?